# JavaFX Virtual Keyboard Layout

Tags: java, javafx

I use the JavaFX virtual keyboard like this:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true 
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true 
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx
```

How can I set it to the german layout?

Comment: Indeed a bug as mentioned, and given the JDK fix rate it may be worth to look into FKVK.java and FKVKSkin.java sources and replicate the functionality until it is fixed and your build is switched to the fixed JDK. Probably on `String boardFileName = type.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1).toLowerCase() + "Board.txt";` line it can be changed to load your own resource and then use the replicated classes instead of the default VK.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is reported as a bug, which doesn't seem to be fixed yet :

> Hi, I've been playing on with the virtual keyboard lately on my
>   desktop by running with -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx and I
>   could not help but notice that the virtual keyboards for text, url and
>   email inputs all have a QWERTY key layout.
>
> I currently run on a system configured to en_AU with a US keyboard but
>   even if I force the JVM to start with fr_FR support as the default
>   locale, the layout of the virtual keyboard remains QWERTY. If I go to
>   Windows' regional settings and change the input method from au+US
>   keyboard (removing it completely) to fr+FR keyboard the virtual
>   keyboard in JavaFX remains QWERTY as well.
>
> I haven't tested on embedded (Raspberry Pi) yet to check if the same
>   was happening on those systems.
>
> This is an issue: if we run a kiosk application on embedded + touch
>   screen, French customers expect to have access to an AZERTY virtual
>   keyboard. Furthermore, if we intend to run an application that is
>   accessible by a wide range of customers, we may want to change the
>   virtual keyboard layout depending of the language that has been
>   selected by the user on the welcome screen (ie: users selecting
>   English would get an QWERTY virtual keyboard, users selecting French
>   would get an AZERTY keyboard).

See : [[Keyboard] Support alternative key layout for virtual keyboard](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090710)